# wxPython - frame without visible content until resize

Tags: wxpython

I have a frame 800x600px. It looks ok (800x600px). I have a function to change my panel:

```
def change(self, evt): 
    self.Destroy()
    Ustawienia(frame)
    frame.Show()
    frame.Centre()
```

In the bottom of my code it is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, size=(800, 600))
Glowne(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

It works ok but result is as on the image. When I maximize window (resize it) it looks ok. It is 800x600 but with no content text until I resize window. Where is an error in my code?

This is working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx, xlrd, os, sys, json
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
with open('config1.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

class Glowne(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    global workbook, sheet, col, col1, vsizer1, b, hsizer2, vsizer2, vsizer3
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    with open('config1.json', 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(os.pardir, config['plik']['rejestr']))
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)
    sheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    col = sheet.col(8)  # 1st row
    col1 = sheet1.col(8)

    linia = wx.StaticLine(self, size=(600,1))

    vsizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)   # wszystkie + plik rejestru
    hsizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) # buttony   
    hsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) # nazwy rewirów


    vsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # zliczone sprawy rewir1
    vsizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # zliczone sprawy rewir2
    hsizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) # sprawy obok siebie rewirami

    plik = 'Aktualnie wybrany plik to: ' + config['plik']['rejestr']

    font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    rej = wx.StaticText(self, 1, plik, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    rej.SetFont(font)

    #self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Zlicz sprawy", (300, 50))
    self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, u"Zmień plik rejestru")
    self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, u"Ustawienia (dodawanie/usuwanie pracowników)")

    b = 2
    vsizer1.Add(rej, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, b)

    #hsizer1.Add(self.btn2, 1, wx.ALL, b)
    hsizer1.Add(self.btn, 1, wx.ALL, b)
    hsizer1.Add(self.btn1, 1, wx.ALL, b)

    hsizer3.Add(vsizer2, 2,  wx.ALL, b)
    hsizer3.AddSpacer((140,0))
    hsizer3.Add(vsizer3, 2,  wx.ALL, b)

    z = wx.StaticText(self, 1, u'DZIAŁ I')
    z.SetFont(font)
    hsizer2.Add(z, 1,wx.ALL, b)
    z1 = wx.StaticText(self, 1, u'DZIAŁ II')
    hsizer2.AddSpacer((180,0))
    z1.SetFont(font)
    hsizer2.Add(z1, 1,wx.ALL, b)

    vsizer1.Add(hsizer1, 1,wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, b)
    vsizer1.Add(hsizer2, 0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, b)
    vsizer1.Add(linia, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 10)
    vsizer1.Add(hsizer3, 5,wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, b)

    self.SetSizer(vsizer1)
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.wyswietlanie_cale, self.btn2)
    self.wyswietlanie()
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.change, self.btn)

def change(self, evt):
    self.Destroy()
    frame.SetTitle('Ustawienia programu')
    Ustawienia(frame)


def wyswietlanie(self):
    '''Funkcja, która zlicza i wyświetla ilość spraw pracowników'''
    #self.btn2.Disable()
    with open('config1.json', 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)
    policzone_1 = []
    policzone_2 = []
    z = 0
    for nazw in config['dzial1']:
        print nazw
        print config['dzial1'][nazw]
        x = config['dzial1'][nazw]   #nazwisko z pliku excela
        print x
        nazwisko = 0
        for index, cell_obj in enumerate(col1):
            if cell_obj.value == x:
                nazwisko += 1
        policzone_1.append((nazw, nazwisko))

    for nazw in config['dzial2']:
        print nazw
        print config['dzial2'][nazw]
        x = config['dzial2'][nazw]   #nazwisko z pliku excela
        print x
        nazwisko = 0
        for index, cell_obj in enumerate(col):
            if cell_obj.value == x:
                nazwisko += 1
        policzone_2.append((nazw, nazwisko))

    posortowane1 = sorted(policzone_1,key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    posortowane2 = sorted(policzone_2,key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    for i in posortowane1:
        print i
        z += 20
        wynik = '%s: %s' % (i[0], i[1]) 
        sprawy = wx.StaticText(self, -1, wynik)
        vsizer2.Add(sprawy, 1,wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALL, b)


    for i in posortowane2:
        print i
        z += 20
        wynik = '%s: %s' % (i[0], i[1]) 
        sprawy = wx.StaticText(self, -1, wynik)
        vsizer3.Add(sprawy, 1,wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALL, b)


class Ustawienia(wx.Panel):
    with open('config1.json', 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    global odstep, odstep1
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.SetSize((800,600))
    odstep = 0
    odstep1 = 0
    font = wx.Font(13, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    for nazwisko in config['dzial1']:
        odstep += 22
        self.nazwisko1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, nazwisko, (100, 10 + odstep))
        self.nazwisko1.SetFont(font)
        btn_usuwanie = wx.Button(self, -1, u"Usuń", (275, 10 + odstep))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, i: Program.Usuwanie(evt, i), btn_usuwanie)
    wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'DZIAL I', (110, 0), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER).SetFont(font)
    print odstep
    for nazwisko in config['dzial2']:
        odstep1 += 22
        self.nazwisko2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, nazwisko, (460, 10 + odstep1))
        self.nazwisko2.SetFont(font)
        self.btn_usuwanie_2 = wx.Button(self, -1, u"Usuń", (650, 10 + odstep1))
        self.btn_usuwanie_2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda nazwisko=self.nazwisko2: self.usuwanie(nazwisko))
    print odstep1
    wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'DZIAL II', (480, 0), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER).SetFont(font)
    self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change panel", (345, 500))
    self.btn_dodaj_dzial1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add name", (100, 42 + odstep))
    self.btn_dodaj_dzial2 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add name", (480, 42 + odstep1))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda rewir: self.nowy_pracownik(self, 'dzial1'), self.btn_dodaj_dzial1)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda rewir: self.nowy_pracownik(self, 'dzial2'), self.btn_dodaj_dzial2)


def nowy_pracownik(self, item, rewir):
    nowy_pracownik = []
    prawda = True
    with open('config1.json', 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)
    while prawda:
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, u'Wpisz imię i nazwisko', defaultValue='')
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            result = dlg.GetValue()
            if len(result) > 0:
                prawda = False
            else:
                wx.MessageBox(u'Wpisz coś!!!', 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
            nowy_pracownik.append(result)
        else:
            prawda = False
            dlg.Destroy()
    prawda1 = True
    while prawda1:
        dlg1 = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, u'Wpisz nazwę do wyszukiwania', defaultValue='')
        if dlg1.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            result = dlg.GetValue()
            if len(result) > 0:
                prawda1 = False
            else:
                wx.MessageBox(u'Wpisz coś!!!', 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
            nowy_pracownik.append(result)
        else:
            prawda = False
            prawda1 = False
            dlg1.Destroy()
    config[rewir][str(nowy_pracownik[0])] = str(nowy_pracownik[1])
    with open('config1.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(config, f, sort_keys=True, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
    self.change1(self)

def change1(self,evt): 
    global config
    with open('config1.json', 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)
    self.Destroy()
    Ustawienia(frame)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, size=(800, 600))
    Glowne(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I added `self.SetSize((800,600))`in Ustawienia(wxPanel). I am sorry for ugly code and foreign language...

[image: My new Panel - without visible content]

Comment: Can you provide a small, runnable example? Also what version of wxPython and what OS are you running on?

Comment: I added working code. I use 3.0.2.0 wxPython and Win10.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to call `Layout` on the new panel or on the top level sizer. Usually when you you destroy widgets or panels and replace them with new ones, they don't automatically resize themselves they don't refresh. When you resize, it fires an event that causes the application to refresh the screen. By calling `Layout`, it should do the refresh you need without resizing the frame.